# Svg matrix decomposition

Tags: matrix, svg, rotation, angle, decomposition

In svg we have method `element.getCTM()` which returns a `SVGMatrix` as:

```
[a c e][b d f][0 0 1]
```

I want to calculate sx , sy and angle of rotation from this matrix.

Comment: Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 11):

There is a lot to read and learn on this subject. I'll give a basic answer, but be aware, if you are trying to do a game or animations this is NOT the way to do it.

`a == sx` and `d == sy`, so you'll access these like this:

```
var r, ctm, sx, sy, rotation;

r   = document.querySelector('rect'); // access the first rect element
ctm = r.getCTM();
sx  = ctm.a;
sy  = ctm.d;
```

Now for the rotation `a == cos(angle)` and `b == sin(angle)`. Asin and acos can't alone give you the complete angle, but together they can. You want to use atan since `tan = sin/cos` and for just this kind of problem you actually want to use `atan2`:

```
RAD2DEG = 180 / Math.PI;
rotation = Math.atan2( ctm.b, ctm.a ) * RAD2DEG;
```

If you study the [inverse trigonometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions) and the [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) you'll understand why this works.

Here is W3C's indespensible resource on SVG transformations: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html. Scroll down a bit and you can read a lot more about what I've mentioned above.

UPDATE, example usage how to programmatically do animations. Keep the transformations stored separately and when these are updated, overwrite/update the SVG element transform.

```
var SVG, domElement, ...

// setup
SVG        = document.querySelector( 'svg' );
domElement = SVG.querySelector( 'rect' );
transform  = SVG.createSVGTransform();
matrix     = SVG.createSVGMatrix();
position   = SVG.createSVGPoint();
rotation   = 0;
scale      = 1;

// do every update, continuous use
matrix.a = scale;
matrix.d = scale;
matrix.e = position.x;
matrix.f = position.y;

transform.setMatrix( matrix.rotate( rotation ) );
domElement.transform.baseVal.initialize( transform ); // clear then put
```

Comment: How to find decomposed values for svg animation ?

Comment: What animations do you want to do? What values do you need? Please describe more.

Comment: I want to say that if I've a svg animation where many animation nodes like animateTransform(translate, scale, rotate) and animateMotion are appended to a container node. So if I want to simplify this animation into single translate , rotate , scale and skew which may be possible with the help of ctm because ctm is combined transformation matrix.Do the ques is what values should I put into translate, rotate , scale and skew nodes to get to the current transformation.

Comment: That requires ALOT of work. When you use `animateTransform`, `animateMotion` and other animation elements you are not supposed to control them programmatically. If you want to control animations programmatically you want to work directly with the elements transforms. I updated my answer above with an example.

Comment: I've found out the solution using SVD which gives me matrices like A = USV* where U and V* are the rotation matices and S is scale matrix.Suppose 1st row of U is [a11 a12] and 2nd row is [a21 a22] . How do I get angle about which coordinate system axes is rotated?