# How to calculate SVG g tag transform rotate/translate/scale values from matrix?

Tags: svg, d3.js, coordinate-transformation

I have following details with me :

```
<g transform="matrix(0.96511294,0.26183393,-0.26183393,0.96511294,59.957438,1507.8483)" id="g3783">
      <path />
</g>
```

Need to change above line to:

```
<g transform="translate(?, ?) scale(?, ?) rotate(angle ? ?)">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697966/svg-matrix-decomposition) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359246/how-to-extract-position-rotation-and-scale-from-matrix-svg)

Comment: Thank you so much for use full links.

Comment: I'm just wondering to get mathematical implementation, but links good to get math from code implementation.